# Can the functions be chosen so that they increase/decrease monotonically?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, approximation

Assume we are in the interval [a,b] and we have a function $f\in L^1([a,b])$. Then since the continuous functions are dense in $L^1([a,b])$ we can choose a sequence $f_n$ of continuous functions such that they converge to $f$ in $L^1([a,b])$. I have two questions.

1. This first is easy. I assume we can choose a subsequence so that they also converge Lebesuge a.e.?
2. This is more difficult. Can we choose the sequence such that $|f_m(x)|\le |f_{m+1}(x)|$ Lebesgue a.e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** That is true. This is often implied by an intermediate step of the proof of the completeness of $L^1$.

**2.** We show that such a choice is not always possible.

Choose a measurable set $E\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $0 < \frac{\operatorname{Leb}(E\cap[a,b])}{\operatorname{Leb}([a,b])}<1$ for any $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$, where $\operatorname{Leb}$ is the Lebesgue measure. An important consequence of this property is that, if $F$ is another measurable set such that $\operatorname{Leb}(E\setminus F)=0$, then $F$ is dense in $[0, 1]$.

Now we let $f = \mathbf{1}_{E} + 2\cdot\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]\setminus E}$. We claim that this $f$ serves as a counter-example.

Assume otherwise, so that there exists a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ such that $|f_n|$ is increasing in $n$ a.e. and $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. Since $|f_n| \to |f| = f$ in $L^1$, we may assume that $f_n$'s are non-negative. Also, by passing to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $f_n$ converges pointwise a.e. Then for each $n$, we have $f_n \leq f$ a.e. By the property of $E$, this implies that the set $\{f_n \leq 1 \}$ is dense in $[0, 1]$, and so, $f_n \leq 1$ on all of $[0,1]$ by the continuity of $f_n$. This contradicts the fact that $f \neq 1$ as elements in $L^1$, and therefore the claim is proved. $\square$

Comment: Thank you but there are a couple of things I dont understand: 1. How do you know that the set E exist? 2. How do you get the property starting at the fourth line with the set F? 3. How do you get the sentence "By the poperty of E, this implies that the set $\{f_n\le 1\}$ is dense in [0,1]"?

Comment: @user394334, 1. A standard way of constructing such a set is nesting fat Cantor sets. See [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h32313), for instance. 2. If a measurable set $F$ satisfies the aforementioned property, then for any non-degenerate interval $I\subseteq[0,1]$, we have $\operatorname{Leb}(F\cap I)>0$, and so, $F\cap I\neq\varnothing$. This implies that $F$ is dense in $[0, 1]$. 3. Note that $F=\{f_n\leq 1\}$ satisfies $\operatorname{Leb}(E\setminus F)=0$, i.e., almost every $x \in E$ lies in the set $F=\{f_n\leq 1\}$.